# Check for duplicate images and videos in database/folder

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to check whether an image or video already exists in a mysql database or a specific folder when the names are different. Also note there could be 10 to 1000 images in the database or folder and this would need to be done via php.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I didn't really know where to start scanning and comparing the images so videos, so if there are any examples to help me get started I would appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file will (for practical purposes) have a unique hash, so you can save the hashes of your files (see [`sha1_file`](http://php.net/sha1_file) or [`md5_file`](http://php.net/md5_file)) to the db and if the hash of your new file is in your db, then it already exists.

```
$newFileHash = sha1_file('myNewFile.txt');
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM myHashes WHERE file_hash = '$newFileHash'";
$rs = mysqli_query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)) {
  echo "the file already exists!";
}
else {
  //insert $newFileHash into your db here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the base64 encoded data information of the images/videos

```
$file = file_get_contents('path/file.zip');
$file_encoded = base64_encode($file);
```

And then compare the `$file_encoded` with whatever you have in your database.

```
if ($file_encoded === $file_encoded_in_db) {
   //Files are the same
}
```